# Python Override non class functions

Tags: python, overriding

with the code below when I run file a.py the output expectedly is "hello" and with file b.py  I want to override bar() from a so I get a "Goodbye" as a result

My goal with this is to change a more complicated function alongside of a program while implementing simpler functions in the main program

I understand that classes would work if a.py contained a class the b imported but that is a fair bit of overhead to rework my code to be a class

file a.py:

```
def foo ():
    print (bar())

def bar ():
    return "hello"

if(__name__=='__main__'):
    foo()
```

output

```
hello
```

file b.py:

```
from a import *

def bar():
    return "Goodbye"

if(__name__=='__main__'):
    foo()
```

output

```
hello
```

Class Implementation

file a_class.py

```
class a:
    def foo (self):
        print (self.bar())

    def bar (self) -> str:
        return "hello"

if(__name__=='__main__'):
    a().foo()
```

output

```
hello
```

file b_class.py

```
from a_class import a
class b(a):
    def bar (self) -> str:
        return "Goodbye"

if(__name__=='__main__'):
    b().foo()
```

output

```
Goodbye
```

edit* grammer

Comment: This seems fairly standard and one line in each file seems not to be `"a fair bit of overhead "`.

Comment: is this only me who is not able to understand your question

Comment: @DeepakTripathi: Well, its just a way of saying that with classes you can override methods, but with modules you can't really override functions.

Comment: You can't override module functions for the same reason you can't make a smoothie with a potato peeler. That tool was not designed for that task, and you need to use the tool that *is* designed for the task.

Comment: I abstracted the code to just an example of what I wanted to ask rather than dump 1000 lines of code and too many other questions to ask,

So a Class structure would be a necessity to implement overrides or duplicate all code relevant to the overridden functions

Comment: A `class` structure is fairly standard and well known. It also give you the option of having different classes that have different combinations of overrides.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has mentioned my only options would be to change my code to Object Oriented or to duplicate all the dependent functions into the new module

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).